# Wait for multiple readyStates for Chromedriver Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to wait for the driver until it reaches the interactive state or complete state.

I use || as the or operator but it has syntax error.

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'interactive' || driver.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete')
```

May I know how to fix it?

Comment: The only other state is loading so you can just do ` != 'loading' `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selenium is going to wait until the 'complete' state by default in almost all cases. That said, to answer your question you can move the comparison inside the JS

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script("return document.readyState == 'interactive' || document.readyState == 'complete'");
```